# How do I access the JSO on socket.on()?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

Here is what I have:

Client Side:

```
socket.on('PING__',function (data){
    console.log(data);
});
socket.emit('__PING');
```

Server Side:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var connection = socket;
    socket.on('__PING', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('PING__' , {status:'OK'});
    });
});
```

The console logs out "object {status:'OK'}".
If I do this instead on the client:

```
console.log(data.status);
```

I get undefined.  I don't understand why it isn't logging out the status portion of the JSO.  Any help here would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a platform-dependent issue.  It occurred within Chromium, but not within Firefox.  I did this:

```
console.log($(data)[0].status);
```

And it worked fine.  Yet another reason to use jQuery for cross-platform issues :-/